# How can I convert from hexadecimal string to normal string?

Tags: java, android, hex, converters

I received to HTTP GET response as hexadecimal string data with socket in java. But I want to convert normal string to this data for HTML format. How can I make it ?

Comment: Dod you try to google it?

Comment: Yes, of course. But I didn't want to any library file. It makes with apache library. I thought maybe there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(YourhexString .toCharArray());
String s=new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmad Alsanie. Is there any way without library ?